# How do I change the scratch message in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

The scratch message always says:

```
;; This buffer is for notes you don't want to save, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
;; then enter the text in that file's own buffer.
```

How do I remove this and make the blank scratch message the default?

Comment: Good grammar is definitely lost on the default `*scratch*` message. http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/05/21/opinion/draft-comma2/draft-comma2-blog427.jpg

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can customize this variable `'initial-scratch-message` to be whatever message you want.

```
(setq initial-scratch-message "")
```

Comment: Is there a difference in setting `initial-scratch-message` to `""` as opposed to `nil`? Both seem to work!

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza No, functionally the two are the same for this variable.

Answer (score 26):

For Emacs 23, you can do this:

```
(setq initial-scratch-message nil)
```

From the documentation: "Initial message displayed in *scratch* buffer at startup. If this is nil, no message will be displayed."

Comment: You can also set this through customize by typing `M-x customize-variable RET initial-scratch-message RET` and setting Value Menu to none.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the initial splash screen with

```
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
```

this appears to also remove the initial message in the scratch buffer.

Comment: Could it be version specific?  I'm running emacs-22.3.  The documentation for initial-scratch-message says:

Initial message displayed in *scratch* buffer at startup.
If this is nil, no message will be displayed.
If `inhibit-startup-screen' is non-nil, then no message is displayed,
regardless of the value of this variable.

(note inhibit-startup-message is an alias for inhibit-startup-screen, at least on my version)

Comment: I'm using Emacs 23.0. Could be an API change.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like an API change. From the NEWS file for Emacs 23.1: The option `inhibit-startup-screen` (with aliases to old names
`inhibit-splash-screen` and `inhibit-startup-message`) doesn't inhibit display of the initial message in the *scratch* buffer.  If you don't want to display the initial message in the *scratch* buffer at startup, you can set the option `initial-scratch-message` to nil.

Comment: "people have gotten great at immediately turning off that annoying startup screen" ... "well, we have to find SOME way to force them to spend even more time configuring the program. otherwise, someone might actually think emacs is accessible or user-friendly!" ... "you're right.  let's just separate that initial configuration step into two stages for now"